# Mingw64: Cannot find CreateSymbolicLink under W10

Tags: c, windows, mingw-w64

Stupid question, but where is CreateSymbolicLink under MinGW64 on Windows 10? I included Windows.h, but CreateSymbolicLink is nowhere to be found, along with the constants. I checked MSDN already, and they say including Windows.h is all you have to do.

Comment: mingw-w64 uses customized versions of the Windows headers, so I guess you're using a very old version that doesn't declare `CreateSymbolicLink`.

Comment: Any way to get a newer version?